# Django define procedure

Tags: django, postgresql, stored-procedures, orm

I would like to define a few PostgreSQL stored procedures in Django for later use, but I cannot find any support from Django to achieve this. I can do this by writing separate python script or SQL file, however I prefer to use Django migration feature. Anyone has done this before?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used stored procedures with Django migration.

However, I am wondering: does it make sense? A stored procedure is not going to change your database schema in most of cases, therefore from my point of view you don't need to make a migration for it